# JOIN two tables to show already purchased items

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table where I keep all my templates:

**templates**

- template_id
- template_name
- template_price

These templates can be purchased by a registered user and then are inserted in the `payments` table:

**payments**

- payment_id
- template_id
- user_id

Is there a way to join these two tables and get not just a list of templates that have been purchased by a certain user, but all the templates? And then figure out from there which ones have already been purchased?

I used this SELECT, but only the ones that the user bought showed up. I would like to have all the rows from `templates`, but empty in case the `user_id` doesn't match.

```
SELECT *
FROM templates
LEFT JOIN payments
ON templates.template_id = payments.template_id
WHERE user_id = 2
GROUP BY templates.template_id
```

Comment: Don't you mean 'I would like to have all the rows from payments, but empty in case the user_id doesn't match'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a subselect this would be

```
SELECT t.*, p.payment_id
FROM templates t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM payments WHERE user_id=2
) p ON t.template_id = p.template_id
```

This shows you all the templates and the payment_id, if there is one for that user.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.*, IF(p.user_id IS NULL, 'not purchased', 'purchased ') AS is_purchased 
FROM templates t
LEFT JOIN payments p
ON t.template_id = p.template_id
GROUP BY t.template_id
```

Comment: This won't select only one users payments

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM  templates
LEFT  JOIN payments
ON    templates.template_id = payments.template_id
AND   user_id = 2 -- <-- change Where to and
GROUP BY templates.template_id
```

Comment: tip : you can write `USING(template_id)` instead of  `ON    templates.template_id = payments.template_id`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT templates.template_id, templates.template_name, templates.template_price, payments.user_id
FROM  templates
LEFT  JOIN payments
ON    templates.template_id = payments.template_id
```

This will show all the templates, BUT does not give you an unique list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using `UNION`

```
SELECT  b.template_name, 'purchased' `status`
FROM    payments a
            INNER JOIN templates b
                on a.template_id = b.templateID
WHERE a.user = 2
UNION
SELECT  template_name, 'not purchased' `status`
FROM templates 
WHERE template_name NOT IN
(
    SELECT  b.template_name
    FROM    payments a
                INNER JOIN templates b
                    on a.template_id = b.templateID
    WHERE a.user = 2
)
```